# How to get indexPathForSelectedRow when a UIButton is pressed inside a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the indexPath for the selected row by pressing a button inside a custom UITableViewCell.

**I have in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
self.rCell.reportUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

**and in my prepareForSegue:**

```
ReportUserViewController *reportUserVC = segue.destinationViewController;

reportUserVC.message = [self.receivedMessages objectAtIndex:self.rCell.reportUserButton.tag];
```

here is my issue...
`self.rCell.reportUserButton.tag` is set to the value of the last cell in view.

If I want the first cell, the last cell is always being set.

**How do I get the indexPath for the cell that has the active Report User button????**

Comment: What is self.rCell?? Why are you keeping a reference to one cell?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `delegate method` on click of your `cell button` to tell it about the `tableViewController`.

```
@protocol cellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)calledOnButtonClick:(CustomCell *)cell;

@end
```

Then on button Click event of your cell call the delegate like

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calledOnButtonClick:)]) 
{
    [delegate calledOnButtonClick:self];
}
```

Now at your tableViewController

```
-(void)calledOnButtonClick:(CustomCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

it will give you the correct index path

Answer (score 0):

cellForRowAtIndexPath call when cell created and reused in table view, you assign value like below code means only last reused cell indexPath assigned to your cell.

```
self.rCell.reportUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Use delegate in cell to pass values

```
// In CustomCell Class
@protocol yourdelegate <NSObject>

-(void)passCellIndexAction:(CustomCell *)cell;

@end

-(void)buttonClickAction
{
   [delegate passCellIndexAction: self];
}

// In View controller class
-(void)passCellIndexAction:(CustomCell *)cell
{
ReportUserViewController *reportUserVC = segue.destinationViewController;
reportUserVC.message = [self.receivedMessages objectAtIndexcell.reportUserButton.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing it:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

For example if using a custom **Details** button and a **segue** from that button to a details view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"news-detail"]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: ((UIButton *)sender).superview.superview.center];
        NSArray *keys = [self.dataSource allKeys];
        NSDictionary *newsItem =  [[self.dataSource objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ;

        [(MyDetail_ViewController *) segue.destinationViewController setDataItem:newsItem];
    }
}
```

Comment: indexPathForRowAtPoint is the way to go, but your use of superview.superview.center assume the layout of the view hierarchy. You should use convertPoint, something like this:          let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)